# Restore GitLab repositories from backup file

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have virtual machine with GitLab 11.11.3 (installed from source). The instance is in a state from few months back. I have more recent backup (few days old) produced by GitLab backup `bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production SKIP=artifacts`. I need to restore the state of GitLab and repositories.

What I did was to restore the backup:

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:restore RAILS_ENV=production BACKUP=XYZ
```

However this restored only content of GitLab not the actual git repository on the machine. The repository dir has git log entries from few months back and gitlab web shows *Can't find HEAD commit for this branch*. I'm bit confused what the next step should be. There is git bundle extracted in backup dir I suppose from the gitlab:backup. It contains empty project dirs and project.bundle files. I've looked up the GitLab documentation page about restore, there are no further steps described after invoking restore.

I've tried to git push from one of the cloned repos. This is seemed to work, but I don't think it's the proper way and the result won't be 100 percent up to date.

Is it possible to update the repositories (to make them up to date) using those git bundle files or I have to use data from cloned repository with more recent content? If so how?

Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: To clarify your intentions : you want to have a second copy of your git+gitlab setup, loaded with the repositories and data from your current production environment, correct ?

Comment: @LeGEC I want to restore original setup after hw failure. It's old vm backup, but I have current gitlab backup file available. I want to get to the original state before previous hw failed.

Comment: ok. Backup file should be a an archive (`.tar`, `.tgz` ...), can you confirm that the backup contains a copy of your repo ? To list the content of a tar archive without extracting it : `tar -t -f <archive>.tar | less`, add the `-z` option if it is a gzipped archive (`.tgz` or `.tar.gz`) ; for example you can search for a file named `master` or `HEAD` in this list, or a folder named after your project.

Comment: @LeGEC Backup file doesn't contain file master nor HEAD. It contains git bundles. eg. repo_1.bundle. I think solution is to clone bare repository from the bundle file. Dunno if it could break something in gitlab.

Comment: ok : you can inspect that bundle. Extract just that file to your disk : `tar -x -f backup.tar path/to/repo.bundle`, then clone it locally, and inspect the commits in there (are they recent enough ?)

Comment: If it  is up to date, you can push its content to the remote.

Comment: yes, it's up to date

Answer (score 1):

From your comments : you found an up to date bundle in the backup, so that's good.

You can check more closely the logs of `rake gitlab:backup:restore` to see if there is a reason why the bundle wasn't restored as the repo,

or you can find a way to manually sync the remote repo (the one in the gitlab wm) with the bundle's data :

- use `git bundle unbundle` to unpack all the refs from that bundle, and push them to gitlab,
- add the bundle as a local remote, fetch from the bundle and push to gitlab,
- copy the bundle on the vm, and unbundle from there,
- ...

Comment: Thank you for help. Unbundling is unnecessary. The best solution was to setup bundle as remote origin directly in existing bare repositories on the gitlab server and just do git fetch in them.